# How to convert Object(with value) into Map

Tags: kotlin

I have a object that I want to print it into string [key1=value1&key2=value2...etc] **without the null value key value pair** and comma into &.

So first of all i think of putting it into a map but it won't work and I don know how it work either.

```
val wxPayOrderObj = WxPayOrder(appid = "wx0b6dcsad20b379f1", mch_id = 
            "1508334851", nonce_str = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),sign = null,
            body = "QQTopUp", out_trade_no = "20150806125346", total_fee = req.total_fee,
            spbill_create_ip = "123.12.12.123",
            trade_type = "JSAPI", openid = "oUpF8uMuAJO_M2pxb1Q9zNjWeS6o")
```

so the output will be

```
    appid=wx0b6dc78d20b379f1&mch_id=150788851&nonce_str=UUID.randomUUID().toString()&
body=QQTopUp&out_trade_no=20150806125346&total_fee=req.total_fee&
spbill_create_ip=123.12.12.123&trade_type=JSAPI&openid=oUpF8uMuAJO_M2pxb1Q9zNjWeS6o
```

anyone please help me, thanks in advances.

Comment: You write something about "putting it into a map", but there is no map. Then you write "it doesn't work either", but we do not see what's not working. What did you do exactly? Do you want to `override fun toString() = "key1=$value1&key2=$value2..."`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question, but you want to convert object to string (to a format that you want)?

Override the object's `toString()` to return "[key1=value1&key2=value2...etc]"

example

```
override fun toString(){
   // make sure you compute the data first
   val answer = "[key1=$value1&key2=$value2...etc]"
   return answer
}
```

The `$` is used in string templates (That's directly writing the name of a variable, the value will be used later to be concatenated) with other strings)